# Executing query with Hive, Tez and offset

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh, tez

I am trying to execute offset query in hive where I am trying to exclude particular records, but always getting the error below:

Query:

```
select * from sample order by id limit 1 OFFSET 1;
```

Error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:41 missing EOF at 'OFFSET' near '1'
```

I tried dropping table and creating it again as suggested in of the SO post, but still getting the same error. Also I have already set `TEZ engine` in hive for faster data processing but the above query launches map reduce jobs.
Why is it so? When I execute another query it gives me direct results `via TEZ engine`.
Can anybody explain me this weird behaviour and as well as in solving my problem?

Environment:

```
1) Cloudera 5.12  
2) Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.12.0
```

Comment: Cloudera does not have Tez.

Comment: i dont know about the earlier cloudera versions but it works in the version which i have mentioned. Try this : set hive.exec.engine=tez;. It works

Comment: It still runs in MR mode. I know for a fact that Tez is not installed or configured, even in the latest CDH

Comment: But if you execute other queries after setting tez as your engine, it doesn't launch map reduce jobs why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why you tagged MySQL, but `OFFSET` does not exist as part of HiveQL SELECT syntax.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select

Comment: so how can i achieve this functionality in hive ?? i tried using limit(1,2) but still getting the same error

Comment: Link which is mentioned by you doesn't provide any information related to supporting functions . Instead they have executed one query with limit which i have already executed but getting the same error. Can you give me more clarity on this ? Thanks

Comment: It's the syntax I linked to. Your error in the question says `missing EOF at 'OFFSET'` because `OFFSET` exists in Mysql and Postgres, not HiveQL. If you want only the second row `LIMIT 1,1` is correct, but **added in Hive 2.0**, which you're not using. Your other option would be generate a row ID using `ROW_NUMBER` function, then filter `ID > 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can include the OFFSET clause with the LIMIT clause to produce paged result sets, like 11-20. 
Always use this clause in combination with ORDER BY (so that it is clear which item should be first, second, and so on) and LIMIT (so that the result set covers a bounded range, such as items 0-9, 100-199, and so on).

Comment: Query pls because i tried many queries for offset but not working in hive